# Is there a word for omniscience without foreknowlege?

Tags: free-will, omniscience

Whenever I look into arguments about omnisciences, it seems to always assume that it also means that foreknowlege exists. I often see this when I look up the paradox of free will. What I am wondering is if there is a concept or word that essentially means "knows everything about the state of the present"?

Comment: It is still called omniscience, but under a different view of free will. "Omniscience" means knowing everything there is to know. Libertarians about free will hold that propositions depending on free choices do not have truth values until the choice is made. So God is omniscient despite not knowing the outcomes of free choices because there is nothing to know there, see [SEP, Foreknowledge and Free Will](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/free-will-foreknowledge/#ArisSolu).

Answer (score 2):

Further to Conifold's comment, and working under an (admittedly precarious) assumption that you are asking this question because of the omniscience/free will paradox...

It seems possible to argue that:

1. The future may be impossible to know.
2. If omniscience means: 'Knowing all that is *possibly* known'. ​
3. Omniscience therefore does not require knowledge of the future.

One problem is that this definition of omniscience seems to contradict the notion of omnipotence (where omnipotence is defined as 'unlimited power'). But of course, we can also limit 'unlimited power' to the 'ability to do that which is possible'.

What then, is divinely possible? And who are we to presume what is divinely possible?

The fact is that the notion of godliness is malleable, so any godly attributes not explicitly and somehow incontrovertibly defined in a sacred text can be tailored to suit the preferences or assumptions of the reader. Are 'omniscience' and 'omnipotence' strictly defined in the Bible? Does its definition vary across Bible translations? Do all - roughly 45,000 - denominations of Christianity ascribe to uniform definitions?

To more directly address the apparent context of your question:

Yes, omniscience can be tailored to meet the needs of a god so that the god can retain the quality of omniscience without contradicting logic. But the louder question then emerges:

Why can't a god - via omnipotence - surpass any logic that seems to prove omniscience and free will incompatible? Why does logic apply to a being who remains - at least according to many interpretations of divinity - beyond our capacity to thoroughly comprehend? Aren't we being arrogant and or foolish to suppose that the limits of our human understanding are relevant to such a transcendent being?

(If your question was not concerned with the omniscience/free-will paradox, let me know and I will remove this answer).

Answer (score 2):

The word is just "omniscience" which means knowing all that *can* be known. Knowing everything about the present is not possible for something within the universe, so it must be a property of some kind of divine being. If foreknowledge is not possible (as, for example, Open Theists teach) then omniscience means knowing everything about the present, and presumably all possible futures, but not what decisions each free will will make.

Answer (score 1):

In a deterministic world, knowing the current state means knowing all future states - Laplace's demon. Even if you consider the Many Worlds Interpretation true, preserving determinism across many worlds, work on [blackhole three body mechanics](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.04029) seems to show different outcomes based on uncertainties below the Planck length, suggesting Laplace's demon at best can only know a constrained set of outcomes.

The Christian god is not considered 'embodied', or restricted in any way.  I'd argue a number of theological frameworks kind of cast a shadow on this theology. A Platonic idea of deity/ies as ultimate or more ultimate reality (which I think bears comparison to Adi Shankara in Hindu thought). And Zoroastrian/Gnostic ideas of the material as fundamentally corrupted/corrupting, with the 'spiritual' or godly in some way beyond or outside it. Substrate independence can give us the idea of things 'beyond' specific instantiation, but not 'outside' it.

It's interesting that the physical realities involved in information are not considered in relation to omniscience. I think this is worth doing as a thought-experiment, extending Laplace's. We are beginning to understand, how vastly much less information is involved in knowing the current state, than in calculating the set of future states, with (Planck scale) uncertainties propagating. So we can picture omniscience by degrees, that depends on the total information a deity has access to. I don't think there is a word to address this difference, but there should be.

Comment: Minor revision: In a deterministic world, knowing the current state AND knowing all the deterministic laws AND having unlimited computational capacities, means knowing all future states.